# Varargs in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to pass arbitrary number of arguments of different types into a function and use these types. It looks [like following](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%3E(a%253A%2520A)%253A%2520A%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%252C%2520C%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B%252C%2520c%253A%2520C)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%2520%2526%2520C%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%252C%2520C%252C%2520D%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B%252C%2520c%253A%2520C%252C%2520d%253A%2520D)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%2520%2526%2520C%2520%2526%2520D%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Afunction%2520f(...args%253A%2520any%255B%255D)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520Object.assign(%257B%257D%252C%2520...args)%253B%250D%250A%257D%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520smth%2520%253D%2520f(%257B%2520x%253A%25201%2520%257D%252C%2520%257B%2520y%253A%25202%2520%257D%252C%2520%257B%2520z%253A%25203%2520%257D)%253B%250D%250Avar%2520res%2520%253D%2520smth.x%2520%252B%2520smth.y%2520%252B%2520smth.z%253B):

```
function f<A>(a: A): A;
function f<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
function f<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
function f<A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;

function f(...args: any[]) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...args);
}

var smth = f({ x: 1 }, { y: 2 }, { z: 3 });
var res = smth.x + smth.y + smth.z;
```

As I want arbitrary number of parameters, I'd like to get rid of these declarations

```
function f<A>(a: A): A;
function f<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
function f<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
function f<A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;
```

and use a single declaration like:

```
function f<...T>(args: [...T]): &<...T>;
```

but this thing is syntactically wrong.

Is there a way to rewrite it in a correct way?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/838771/178988)

Comment: Related: [Proposal: Variadic Kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)

Comment: @CRice, no workaround in my case, except specifiing tons of overloads? Also seems like proposal is only about arrays and I don't see there anything like `&<...T>`.

Comment: There's a little discussion about it in that proposal, and I noticed they link to another issue [describing this almost exactly](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3870). I don't know of any way to do it without overloads currently. Even the [stdlib's definition for `Object.assign`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4434) uses a giant overload. But there may be a way I'm just not aware of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit for 3.0**

While the original answer is correct, since I first gave it typescript has changed. In typescript 3.0 it is possible to use tuples in rest parameters to capture the type of the arguments in a tuple

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

function f<A extends any[]>(...args: A): UnionToIntersection<A[number]> { return null! }
var smth = f({ x: 1 }, new A(), new B());  // will have type  A & B & { x: number; }
```

**Original answer**

While as others have mentioned [Proposal: Variadic Kinds](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) would help with this task, we can find some workarounds for your specific example.

If we write the function signature with a single type argument, we can get a union type of the arguments:

```
function f<A>(...args: A[]): A {}
var smth = f({ x: 1 }, { y: 2 }, { z: 3 });
typeof smth = {
    x: number;
    y?: undefined;
    z?: undefined;
} | {
    y: number;
    x?: undefined;
    z?: undefined;
} | {
    z: number;
    x?: undefined;
    y?: undefined;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that if we use a class instead of an object literal the compiler will refuse to infer the union and give us an error instead. If we let the rest parameter go (`...`) and just use an array the compiler will infer a union of the parameter type:

```
function f<A>(args: A[]): A { /*…*/}
var smth = f([{ x: 1 }, new A(), new B()]); 
typeof smth == A | B | {
    x: number;
}
```

So now we have a union of types, but you want an intersection. We can convert the union to an intersection using conditional types (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) answer)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
(U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function f<A>(args: A[]): UnionToIntersection<A> {
    return Object.assign({}, ...args);
}

class A { z: number }
class B { y: number }

var smth = f([{ x: 1 }, new A(), new B()]); // will have type  A & B & { x: number; }
var res = smth.x + smth.y + smth.z;
```

Hope this helps, and gives you a usable workaround at least until we get variadic kinds.

Comment: Interesting, but in this case it's impossible to specify every type explicitly?

Comment: You can specify the union type and explicitly, but that will not restrict the position and number of times each type can appear. I did mention it's workaround :-)

Comment: @Qwertiy Thank you for bringing this to my attentions. When I answered this 3.0 was not on the horizon and since I have 2500 answers it's hard to updated them all. I try to update answers as they are upvoted or if someone pings me about it, which you did so 10x:)

Comment: Sorry, assidentially deleted the comment. Here is the link: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001736/178988

Comment: what exactly is `number` in the type expression `A[number]`?

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen did you figure out `A[number]`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but the type is working for me.

Comment: @luckydonald I just happened to be thinking about it now, and I believe it means "any element of the array A". Similar to how P[keyof P] would mean "any value of object P". In other words, A[number] evaluates to "the type of the element at some position indexed by a number in array A"